# Cannot use import statement outside a module CLIENT-SIDE

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

At client-side, I want to import only a specific part of my Javascript module.
But I wanna do that on demand, like when a user performs an action that needs that specific part of the module.
I was able to accomplish that in the HTML file, with:

```
<script type="module">
 import { sayHi } from "/public/js/sayHi.js";
 sayHi("John");
</script>
```

Now I want to do the same but in my client-side JS file, so that I run this loading whenever I want (and not on page load, as in the example above). The closest that I got from solving it was running this in my client-side JS file:

```
import("/public/js/sayHi.js")
```

But the problem is that this last script loads the whole module, not just the part that I want. If I try to do this:

```
import { sayHi } from "./sayHi.js";
```

I get the error "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

How can I import only the { sayHi } part via my client-side JS?

P.S.: Just to give an example, I would like to have something like that in my client-side JS:

```
buttonX.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const a = await import { sayHi } from "./sayHi.js";;
});
```

Comment: Importing anything from a module will always load the whole file/module. If you use a dynamic import then you get an object back whose properties are the module exports. So you would access e.g. `(await import("/public/js/sayHi.js")).sayHi`.

Comment: Not possible. From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)... _"Use dynamic import only when necessary. The static form is preferable for loading initial dependencies, and can benefit more readily from static analysis tools and [tree shaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tree_shaking)."_

Comment: Loading/using only part of the file is something some bundlers can do ("tree shaking") but that's a specific feature of those bundlers and works via static analysis, not at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It loads the whole module, not just the part that I want

It always does, you cannot avoid that. This also happens when you use `import {…} from '…'` - it just doesn't import everything into the current module scope. Just like when you call `import(…)`, you don't have to use all available parts:

```
buttonX.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const { sayHi: a } = await import("./sayHi.js");
  a();
});
```